# Serial Number and Product Number of laptop in Windows

Tags: windows, license

How do I get the Product and Serial Number of ASUS EeePC netbook on Windows (XP preferably)?

Edit: I am not a label reader and I am interested to retrieve the two numbers by software or tool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can see two ways to do this:

1. Type "msinfo32" on your "Run"(<kbd>Windows Button</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). Search for "System Model" or "System Serial". Certainly you will find the information that you need here.
2. [SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/)(System Information for Windows):

SIW is an advanced System Information for Windows tool that analyzes your computer and gathers detailed information about system properties and settings and displays it in an extremely comprehensible manner.

Or even a 3th option:

3. If you until don't find what you are looking for, you would try looking over windows registry(<kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> / "regedit"), go to `HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\SYSTEM`. There is a lot of information about your system an about your BIOS here.

Comment: +1 How only you are getting the idea of the question? I`m sorry that I can make it + more!

Comment: @Xavierjazz done :)

Comment: FYI, on my Windows 8 laptop, these locations listed model number, but did not list serial number. Daniel's answer worked for me (command `wmic bios get serialnumber`).

Answer (score 6):

You can also do this from the command line by typing `wmic bios get serialnumber`

This will give you the laptop or desktop computer serial number.

`wmic csproduct get name` will give you the computer model.

I can confirm these both still work in Windows 7.

Documented here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/558124

Comment: On my Windows 8 laptop (Asus RoG), this was the only software location that had the serial number. In locations mentioned in accepted answer, only model number was found.

Comment: `wmic csproduct get name` shows product name, not product number unfortunately. I have to reboot a computer to get the product number

Answer (score 4):

If for some reason the sticker is not there, you can use software tools to recover the product key and get the model of your system.  [Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html) is one such tool.

Comment: I have to update this answer. This tool is the ONLY tool I have found that actually display the accurate product key and is 100% free and doesn't attempt to limit the results nor is there any annoying upselling.

Answer (score 3):

Look [here](http://burzin.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-find-your-eeepcs-serial-number.html).

From the site:

> Overturn your EeePC.  There will be a sticker with with the Serial
>   Number (SN:).  That is your serial number.  But if like mine, with
>   time, the Serial Number on my EeePC has disappeared, then what ?!
>
> Instead of my Serial Number, the sticker has become blank !  Shame on
>   you Asus for using disappearing ink for the serial number.
>
> If you still have your EeePC package box, then the Serial Number (SN:)
>   is printed on the box.  If you don't have the EeePC packing box then
>   you can check the Invoice of your EeePC.  The EeePC serial number will
>   be mentioned in your Invoice.
>
> ...
>
> There is one last way you can find out your Computers manufacturing
>   serial number.
>
> This will only work if you have your original battery.  Remove your
>   battery.  Under the battery you will find a sticker (hopefully as it
>   is hidden inside, the number would not have disappeared with wear and
>   tear).

Comment: You thik I haven`t do that, do you? ...

Comment: We don't know what you've done if you don't tell us...You need to be WAY more specific with your questions if you are going to be this critical of answers.