# How do I find the serial number of my Macbook Pro in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, macbook-pro

How do I find the serial number of my Macbook Pro in Windows 7? I can't read the serial number on the back. It is too small.

I tried steps 1 and 3 in this question: [Serial Number and Product Number of laptop in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/329477/serial-number-and-product-number-of-laptop-in-windows) and none of them worked.

Comment: You should try a magnifying glass. In a pinch, try holding a plastic bottle of water up to it - it should work for magnifying. Alternatively, take a photo, and zoom it, or find someone with better eyes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following command in windows command prompt tool

```
wmic bios get serialnumber
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get the serial number from Windows. I recommend getting the S/N close to a bright light and writing down the S/N as best you can.  You can use this site: https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do?sn=730300257XJ to verify the serial number is correct. It will show you the Ghz which you can verify by going to System Properties (right click on My Computer and select properties)